# How to check number of rows of SAS data (.sas7bdat) without reading in R

Tags: r, sas

I have a large SAS file to process, and I need to access the number of rows before process them in chunks.

Is there a fast way to check the number of rows before reading in `R`?

I used `length(count.fields(data))` but not satisfied with the speed.

Edit: Loading the data into R is not a viable option for my case.

Comment: How much information do you know about the dataset?  In particular: is it compressed? And do you know the total row size (how many bytes a row takes up)?

Comment: What R package are you using to read the SAS dataset?  Does it offer an option to just return the observation count from the dataset's metadata?

Comment: @Joe The only info I know is the data is stored in .sas7bdat and .sas7bndx files and I have limited knowledge whether it is compressed.

Comment: @Tom I'm trying to use package `haven`, but if you happen to know other package that are more efficient please let me know. AFAIK `haven` does not have the feature I'm trying to do.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this via programming. You can view it in Universal Viewer to get the number of rows. Is this a one time process or something you'll need to repeat regularly.

Comment: Don't know about R packages, but this python package has a metadata only option. https://github.com/Roche/pyreadstat#reading-only-the-headers

Answer (score 0):

You can check the header (nobs) in SAS as below

```
data _null_;
if 0 then set mydata nobs=nobs;
call symputx("nobs",nobs);
stop;
run;
```